# CSS attribute selector not working as expected

Tags: css

Hi can someone help me write a complex selector where i find all HREFs that do not contain the word "video" in the link are selected

```
.ico-wrap[href:not([href*="/video/"])]
```

Need help with the href:not part. Thank you

Comment: `.ico-wrap:not([href*="/video/"])`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have one too many `href`s in there.

```
.ico-wrap:not([href*="/video/"])
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/w3kKM/

This will select elements without an `href` value, if you want to only select elements with an `href`, then you can do:

```
.ico-wrap[href]:not([href*="/video/"])
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/w3kKM/1/